# How to use .pem file inside Amazon Lambda to access EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pem

I'm currently working on a project that take place inside the AWS environment. I have configure a S3 bucket in order to receive mails (mails are coming from  SES but that's not relevant).

What I want to do is to create a Lambda function that will be able to access a EC2 instance and launch a python scripts. So far i have the code below. The problem is that when I created my ec2 instance, I didnt create any username or password to connect via SSH. I only have a .pem file (certificate file) to authenticate to the instance.

I did some research but i couldn't find anything useful.

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
var ssh = new SSH({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password'
});

ssh.exec('python3.6 path/to/my/python/script.py', {
    out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
}).start();
```

i've been thinking of severals solutions, but i'm not sure at all :

- find an SSH library in Javascript that handle .pem file
- converting .pem into a String (not secure at all, in my opinion).
- maybe create a new ssh user in EC2 ?

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: this seems a little odd tbh - does it *have* to be via SSH? can you use eg an http request?

Comment: Rather than triggering something in an EC2 instance, have you considered having the instance poll an Amazon SQS queue to obtain work? This is a much simpler and reliable method.

Comment: @danimal i wasn't sure on which protocol enable to run command in remote beside SSH.

Comment: To trigger the script to run via an HTTP request to the EC2 instance, you would need a web application running on the EC2 instance 24x7, listening for requests. You could certainly do it this way but it would require some app dev.

Comment: @jarmod now that it is said, it sounds kind of obvious thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better option would be to use AWS Systems Manager to remotely run commands on your Amazon EC2 instances.

If you still choose to use [simple-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh) then you need to supply an SSH key in `config.key` when creating your SSH object. You can store the private key in Parameter Store or Secrets Manager and retrieve it within the Lambda. In this case, you should definitely use passwordless SSH (with keypair).

Comment: Yes your second point is kind of what i want, i'm going to check AWS Systems Manager but i need the approval to my superior. Thanks man !